# Magento 2: Checkout Page New Address Not Saved

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, cookie, customer-address

On Checkout page, I'm Adding " + New Address" by clicking on that.

While saving "Save In Address Book" Checkbox is already checked. Still, it's not saving that address.

Once I Logout & Login that address is not longer available. I didn't complete "Place Order" process.

I have checked by Placing Order as well. Still it's not working.

Is it issue with Cache or Cookie?

Comment: Are you using any custom payment method? If such than check for the  setBillingAddressAction() payment-method.js file.

Comment: We are using Default Paypal Express & Bank Transfer. But issue is i'm checking with Fresh Installation of Magento 2.1.3. No additional module added

Answer (score 3):

I've just debugged the order process for customers.
The Customer Address is only save when you place the order (Not if you save the shipping information by clicking next)

The placeOrder action is called when you complete the payment step:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php#L77

looking at the Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement:placeOrder Method it calls the submit Method which calls the submitQuote which then calls the _prepareCustomerQuote Method, which then adds the address to the customer https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php#L539